# Alternative approach of a step in the proof of the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and denote the closed unit ball in $V$ as $B$ and the closed (with respect to the norm topology) unit ball in $V^*$ as $B^*$. Let $D=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\mid |z|\leq 1\}$. Consider the weak$^*$ topology of $V^*$ restricted on $B^*$ (denoted as $\tau_1$) and the product topology of $D^B$ restricted on $f(B^*)$ (denoted as $\tau_2$) where $f:B^*\to D^B$ is defined as
$$
f(\varphi)=\varphi|_B.
$$

A step in the proof of the Alaoglu Theorem is to show that $(B^*,\tau_1)$ and $(f(B^*),\tau_2)$ are homeomorphic. I can recover this step using net convergence:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map between two topological spaces.  Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for every net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ in $X$ that converges to a limit $x$, the net $(f(x_\alpha))_{\alpha \in A}$ converges in $Y$ to $f(x)$.

I was told that one can work out this by using subbase for $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ instead. But I don't know the details about it. When I try it as an exercise, I find I get stuck after I write down the (possibly wrong) subbase:

For $\tau_1$, the subbasic sets are of the form
$\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h)\in U\}$ for $h\in V$ and $U$ open in $D$. For $\tau_2$, the subbasic sets are of the form $\{ \phi|_B: \phi(h) \in U ,\phi\in B^*\}$ for $h\in B$ and $U$ open in $D$. Denotes these two subbases as $P$ and $Q$.

To show $f$ is an open map, it suffices to show $f(P)\subset \tau_2$. To show $f$ is continuous it suffices to show that $f^{-1}(Q)\subset\tau_1$.

---

[In progress:]
It makes sense now for me that for $\tau_1$, the subbasic sets should be of the form
$\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h)\in U\}$ for $h\in V$ and $U$ open in $\Bbb C$. For $\tau_2$, the subbasic sets are of the form $\{ \phi|_B: \phi|_B(h) \in U\cap D ,\phi\in B^*\}$ for $h\in B$ and $U$ open in $C$.

Now consider in $\tau_2$ the open set $P:=\{ \phi|_B: \phi|_B(h) \in U\cap D ,\phi\in B^*\}$ for some **fixed** $h\in B$ and $U$ open in $\Bbb C$. Why is $f^{-1}(P)$ open in $(B^*,\tau_1)$ (which shows that f is continuous)?

I want to figure out what is $f^{-1}(P)$:
$$
f^{-1}(P)=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi|_B(h)\in U\cap D\}\\
=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h)\in U\cap D\}.
$$
Still, I don't see why $f^{-1}(P)$ is open in $(B^*,\tau_1)$.

Comment: Take neighbourhood sub-bases for each $\varphi$, that is simpler. A neighbourhood sub-basis of $\varphi$ is given by the sets of the form $V_\varphi(b;\varepsilon) = \{ \psi : \lvert \varphi(b) - \psi(b)\rvert < \varepsilon\}$, where $b$ ranges over $B$ and $\varepsilon$ ranges over $(0,+\infty)$. The only difference is that in $f(B^\ast)$ we don't a priori require the $\psi$ to be linear, that comes when intersecting with $f(B^\ast)$.

Comment: Still don't get it... One can show that $f$ is a (set) bijection. If one has a subbase $P$ for $\tau_1$ and $Q$ for $\tau_2$, then what's left to be shown is $f(P)\subset \tau_2$ and $f^{-1}(Q)\subset\tau_1$.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes. $f(P) \subset \tau_2$ shows that $f$ is open (to $f(B^\ast)$, not as a map to $D^B$), and $f^{-1}(Q) \subset \tau_1$ shows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Would you elaborate why taking the nbhd subbases for each $\varphi$ is simpler? I don't see the point. Also, looking at the version you gave, I suspect that the form of subbasic sets for \tau_1$ I wrote is wrong.

Comment: On second thoughts, it doesn't make much of a difference. For both ways, you effectively need only write down the definitions in the right way. Indeed, the form for $\tau_1$ that you gave isn't quite correct, you need to either consider only $h \in B$, so that $\varphi(h) \in D$ for all $\varphi \in B^{\ast}$, or let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$ rather than in $D$. If you take $V = \mathbb{C}$ and $U = \{z\in D : \lvert z-1\rvert < 1/2\}$, for $\lvert h\rvert > 1$ you get a set that isn't open in $B^{\ast}$.

Comment: OK. I eventually come up with a proof, which looks very ugly. I think that might be a reason why people prefer an argument via net convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider in $\tau_2$ the open set $P:=\{ \phi|_B: \phi|_B(h) \in U\cap D ,\phi\in B^*\}$ for some fixed $h\in B$ and $U$ open in $\Bbb C$. Note that
$$
f^{-1}(P)=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi|_B(h)\in U\cap D\}\\
=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h)\in U\cap D\},
$$
which is the same(!) as
$$
\{ \phi \in B^*: \phi(h) \in U \}
$$
since $\phi\in B^*$ and $h\in B$. Note that this is a subbasic set in $(B^*,\tau_1)$. It follows that $f$ is continuous (exercise).

Now we show that $f$ is an open map, which gives the continuity of $f^{-1}$. Consider in $\tau_1$ the open set 
$Q=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h)\in U\}$ for $h\in V$ and $U$ open in $\Bbb C$. Note that $h=\epsilon h'$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $h'\in B$. Then 
$$
Q=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h')\in U'\}
$$
with $U'=\frac{1}{\epsilon}U$, which is also open in $\Bbb C$. Since $h'\in B$, for each $\varphi\in B^*$, we have
$$
\varphi(h')\in D.
$$
It follows that
$$
Q=\{\varphi\in B^*:\varphi(h')\in U'\cap D\}
$$
and thus
$$
f(Q)=\{\varphi|_B:\varphi\in B^*,\varphi|_B(h')\in U'\cap D\},
$$
which is a subbasic set in $\tau_2$. Since $f:B^*\to f(B^*)$ is a bijection, $f(Q)\in\tau_2$ implies that $f$ is an open map.